# Appending all datas from one excel to other excel using python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to merge two excel data into one by appending one excel data to other by using python script.
One excel is excel_1.xlsx and second excel is excel_2.xlsx.

In excel_1.xlsx (parent_sheet) it has following datas:

```
NAME    ROLL_NO  SERVICE_NAME
Raman   12        Vicky
Pinky   3         Raja
Sunena  24        Sneha
Nita    18        Rahul
```

In excel_2.xlsx(child_sheet) it has following datas:

```
 NAME   PLACE   ANIMAL  NUMBERS COLORS  LOCATION    TOY
 Neha   Delhi   cat       6                home      1
        Gujrat            4      pink      home      7
 Raja   UP      dog       5      yellow    home      3
 Sneha  Mumbai  owl       1                home      6
        Pune    parrot    3      green     home      2
        Jaipur  pegion    4                home      4
 Rahul  Raipur            4      purple    home      2
        Nashik  rabbit    2      red       home      9
```

I want when excel_2.xlsx(child_sheet)  "NAME" column matches with excel_1.xlsx(parent_sheet) "SERVICE_NAME". If they both matching then append all the data which are after "NAME" column. Like If "NAME" Sneha of (child_sheet) matches with "SERVICE_NAME" Sneha of (parent_sheet) then append all data of child_sheet to parent_sheet.

For ex.

```
NAME   ROLL_NO  SERVICE_NAME  PLACE   ANIMAL NUMBERS COLORS LOCATION TOY 
Sunena  24       Sneha        Mumbai   owl      1            home    6
                              Pune     parrot   3     green  home    2
                              Jaipur   pegion   4            home    4
```

So i want expected output like this:

```
NAME ROLL_NO  SERVICE_NAME  PLACE  ANIMAL  NUMBERS  COLOR   LOCATION  TOY
Raman   12     Vicky                        
Pinky   3      Raja         UP       dog      5     yellow    home     3
Sunena  24     Sneha        Mumbai   owl      1               home     6
                            Pune     parrot   3     green     home     2
                            Jaipur   pegion   4               home     4
Nita    18     Rahul        Raipur            4     purple    home     2
                            Nashik   rabbit   2     red       home     9
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: @Datanovice need help in this